# Add products to cart from modal popup

Tags: magento2, products, shopping-cart, modal-popup, multiple-add-to-cart

I am showing accessory products on popup and it appears just after adding actual product in cart.

[image: Modal popup after product is added to cart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the form submission mechanism to achieve this.

First I changed the button type from `submit` to `button` to avoid default submission.

Then I programatically added all products with mentioned quantities to cart using ajax request.

Refresh the page afer ajax is complete to get it reflected in mini-art as well as in main shopping cart.